# How to Inject Multiple Startup Config Files in Net Core MVC modular plugin app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, orchard-modules, app-startup

please read **below scenario**:

in a plugin based application built with Plugin Library [DotnetCorePlugins](https://github.com/natemcmaster/DotNetCorePlugins) where a single host application serves with micro plugins everything is working well and good. But i need to do **startup service registration from these plugins** as needed so say **plugin1 introduces a middleware, plugin2 a pipeline, plugin3 some mediatr service etc**...

i dig into OrchardCore & Orchard does that by using a **StartupBase** class but i am unable to find out how they are doing it [if my assumption is correct orchard uses msbuild for plugins unlike loadcontext of this library].

my requirements and structure is different from orchard, but i like the idea of having a StartupBase class
where ***i can define configuration order and service init order*** and it gets called on main host app initilization
can someone guide me to the right way to do this, i am ok with even minimal flow steps as long as its clear to understand.
the Plugin Startup files must handle the defined order in host and be injected into main startup bus.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly... you can register many customizations in Startup like this...

Create a ServiceExtensions Class

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Your.Custom.Namespace
{
    public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureMiddleware(this IServiceCollection services, 
                                                      IConfiguration config)
        {
            // custom stuff
        }
        public static void ConfigurePipeline(this IServiceCollection services, 
                                                      IConfiguration config)
        {
            // custom stuff
        }
        public static void ConfigureMedia(this IServiceCollection services, 
                                                      IConfiguration config)
        {
            // custom stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Then in StartUp, call those methods...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ... other configs
   services.ConfigureMiddleware(Configuration);
   services.ConfigurePipeline(Configuration);
   services.ConfigureMedia(Configuration);
}
```

Comment: you missed the point that i am using a plugin architecture, all assemblies are loaded using reflection & assemblyloadcontext, its not a direct reference to side projects